# Is it secure to build a Cipher object with a SecureRandom object which has a fixed seed?

Tags: java, security, cryptography

A colleague of mine asked me to check if his code is secure enough. I saw some code snippet like this:

```java
    private static byte[] encrypt(String plain, String key) throws Exception {
        KeyGenerator kg = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
        SecureRandom secureRandom = new SecureRandom();
        secureRandom.setSeed(key.getBytes());
        kg.init(128, secureRandom);
        SecretKey secretKey = kg.generateKey();
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
        return cipher.doFinal(plain.getBytes());
    }

    @Test
    public void lcg() throws Throwable {
        String plain = "abc";
        String key = "helloworld";

        byte[] c1 = encrypt(plain, key);
        byte[] c2 = encrypt(plain, key);
        Assert.assertArrayEquals(c1, c2);
    }
```

This `encrypt` function is used to encrypt sensitive data, and encrypted data will be stored into database. I thought it won't work firstly because SecureRandom won't generate same random number twice even initialzed by the same seed, but it just works in the test.

I think it is not secure to encrypt something in this way, but I can't tell what is the problem about this code snippet.

My question:

1. is the `encrypt` function secure?
2. if it's not secure, what is the problem to do so?

Comment: Using SecureRandom in that manner is deprecated and is non-portable. As you note, it may not even generate the same values twice in a row. In fact current and past implementations *have* generated the same values and as a result led to this anti-pattern proliferating. Instead use a proper password-based KDF such as PBKDF2.

Comment: "if it's not secure, what is the problem to do so?" Uh, sorry, I don't get this part of the question. What problem? To do what?

Comment: No it is not secure. In the end it is an static key stored in your program just a little bit obfuscated.

Comment: @Robert The fact that the `lcg` method is annotated with `@Test` makes me think that this application does not necessarily use a static key.

Answer (score 5):

> **is the `encrypt` function secure?**

No, it is not secure for any good definition of secure.

First of all, it uses ECB, which is not secure unless the plaintext blocks are not related.

More importantly, `new SecureRandom()` simply gets the first random number generator from the provider list. Usually this was `"SHA1PRNG"` but currently - for the Oracle Java 11 SE runtime - it returns a much faster and better defined `DRBG`. Those are not compatible, so one ciphertext cannot be decrypted with another runtime; the code is not portable at all.

Different runtimes may return completely different random number generators - possibly optimized for the runtime configuration. These random number generators may depend completely on the given seed *if* it is set before random numbers are extracted from it. It may also *mix* the seed *into* the state. That will produce a completely random key which you will *never* be able to regenerate unless you save it somewhere.

Basically, this method may both be insecure because of ECB and overly secure - not a small feat in itself. You may never be able to decrypt the ciphertext again, ever, but you can still distinguish identical plaintext blocks.

---

A small other problem is that `getBytes` uses the platform default encoding. This differs e.g. between Windows (Windows-1252) and Linux (UTF-8) and the Android platform (also UTF-8, of course). So decode the plaintext on another system - if you can - and you may still get surprised afterwards.

---

The procedure is so bad that it should be archived in the round rubbish receiver and implement something new. For that it is a good idea to use a key and IV consisting of random bytes and a modern cipher such as AES in GCM mode at the very least. If you have a password you should use a password hash (or key-based key derivation function) like PBKDF2 or a more modern one to derive a key from it.

---

Kudo's for finding a worse way to derive keys from passwords. `getRawKey` was bad, but this one is worse. Good that you asked, in other words.

Comment: Thank you. I did not paste the origin code snippet on stackoverflow for some reason, but wrote another one to express the logic in origin one. Finally I find out that this code is copied from the first item of the result list when searching "java aes encrypt" in baidu.com (the most used search engine in china). Good news is that they also fixed the algorithm for SecureRandom and encoding of getBytes. ECB may not be used in origin code, they put the cipher algorithn in a constant.